# big table processing (advice needed)

Tags: r

I have a table of 55000 rows, which looks like that (left table):
[image: sample table]

(the code to generate sample data is below)

Now I need to convert every row of this table to 6 rows, each containing one letter of "hexamer" (right table on the picture) with some calculations:

```
# input for the function is one row of source table, output is 6 rows
splithexamer <- function(x){
  dir <- x$dir # strand direction: +1 or -1
  pos <- x$pos # hexamer position
  out <- x[0,] # template of output
  hexamer <- as.character(x$hexamer)
  for (i in 1:nchar(hexamer)) {
    letter <- substr(hexamer, i, i)
    if (dir==1) {newpos <- pos+i-1;}
    else        {newpos <- pos+6-i;}
    y <- x
    y$pos <- newpos
    y$letter <- letter
    out <- rbind(out,y)
  }
  return(out);
} 


# Sample data generation:
set.seed(123)
size <- 55000
letters <- c("G","A","T","C")
df<-data.frame(
  HSid=paste0("Hs.", 1:size),
  hexamer=replicate(n=size, paste0(sample(letters,6,replace=T), collapse="")),
  chr=sample(c(1:23,"X","Y"),size,replace=T),
  pos=sample(1:99999,size,replace=T),
  dir=sample(c(1,-1),size,replace=T)
)
```

Now I would like to get some advices what would be the most efficient way to apply my function to every row. So far I tried the following:

```
# Variant 1: for() with rbind
tmp <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
tmp<-rbind(tmp,splithexamer(df[i,]));
}

# Variant 2: for() with direct writing to file
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
write.table(splithexamer(df[i,]),file="d:/test.txt",append=TRUE,quote=FALSE,col.names=FALSE)
}

# Variant 3: ddply
tmp<-ddply(df, .(HSid), .fun=splithexamer)

# Variant 4: apply - I don't know correct syntax
tmp<-apply(X=df, 1, FUN=splithexamer) # this causes an error
```

all of the above is extremely slow, I am wondering if there's better way to solve this task...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution using `data.table`:

```
df$hexamer <- as.character(df$hexamer)
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[, id := seq_len(nrow(df))]
setkey(dt, "id")
dt.out <- dt[, { mod.pos <- pos:(pos+5); if(dir == -1) mod.pos <- rev(mod.pos); 
                list(split = unlist(strsplit(hexamer, "")), 
                    mod.pos = mod.pos)}, by=id][dt][, id := NULL]
dt.out
#         split mod.pos     HSid hexamer chr   pos dir
#      1:     G   95982     Hs.1  GCTCCA   5 95982   1
#      2:     C   95983     Hs.1  GCTCCA   5 95982   1
#      3:     T   95984     Hs.1  GCTCCA   5 95982   1
#      4:     C   95985     Hs.1  GCTCCA   5 95982   1
#      5:     C   95986     Hs.1  GCTCCA   5 95982   1
#     ---                                             
# 329996:     A   59437 Hs.55000  AATCTG   7 59436   1
# 329997:     T   59438 Hs.55000  AATCTG   7 59436   1
# 329998:     C   59439 Hs.55000  AATCTG   7 59436   1
# 329999:     T   59440 Hs.55000  AATCTG   7 59436   1
# 330000:     G   59441 Hs.55000  AATCTG   7 59436   1
```

Explanation of the main line:

- The `by=id` will group by `id` and since they are all unique, it'll group by every line, one at a time.
- Then, the ones within `{}` sets `mod.pos` to `pos:(pos+6-1)` and if `dir == -1` reverses it.
- Now, the `list` argument: It creates the column `split` by creating 6 nucleotides from your hexamer using `strsplit` and also sets `mod.pos` which we've already calculated in the step before.
- This will result in a `data.table` with columns `id, split and mod.pos`.
- The next part `[dt]` is a typical usage of `data.table's X[Y]` syntax which performs a join on the data.tables based on the **key column** ( = `id`, here). Since there are 6 rows for every `id` you get all the other columns in `dt` duplicated during this join.

I'd suggest you take a look at `data.table` **FAQ** first and then its **documentation (intro)**. These links can be obtained by installing the package and loading it and then typing `?data.table`. I also suggest you work through the many examples in there one by one with a test data.table to understand practically the features of data.table.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nope. One row of input => 6 rows of output. Look more closely at OP's code.

Comment: wow, that's magic!!! @Arun, thanks a lot! Unfortunately, usage of `data.table` is still kind of mystery for me, and I don't understand how does the last line work. If by chance you can recommend any good manual about `data.table` (better than standard help that goes with the package) - I would be even more grateful.

Comment: I just realized that in fact it is not the full solution for me: if you take a look on my code, the difference between each of 6 rows is not only the letter but also "pos" which is calculated differently depending on the "dir" column of source row. Of course I can now do the reverse step with some kind of aggregation and calculation for each group but I am wondering if it will be as slow as original variant...

Comment: I put another picture as sample table - hope it's more clear now

Comment: @VasilyA, give me a minute.

Comment: @VasilyA, `mod.pos` gives the result you're looking for, I suppose.

Comment: @VasilyA, I've added an explanation of the last line (where seemingly everything is happening) and also pointed you to getting acquainted with data.table. The documentation and FAQ are incredibly well written.

Comment: great, it's indeed just perfect. Thank you very much! I definitively should find some manual and master using `data.table`.

Comment: the manual is already there. type `?data.table` from R and read and follow the links.

Comment: indeed, I just did not notice there is a FAQ in the help. Even better so.